# How to delete a pod in Openshift with restart policy set to always?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-enterprise

Could be a basic one..

I have created a pod in Openshift Enterprise 3.2 with the configuration set as **`restartPolicy: Always`** . So ideally when the pod is destroyed Openshift will make sure to re-run/re-create the pod because of the restart policy.

**Now I no longer need the pod. When I am trying to destroy the pod it is getting created again.**

My question is **What is the ideal way to destroy the pod with** **`restartPolicy: Always`**

Comment: Are you saying you have no associated replication controller or deployment, or deployment config?

Comment: It is associated with deployment config, with replicas set to 1 and restartPolicy: Always. Is this the info you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @Here_2_learn  I suggest you get yourself familiarized with the [core concepts of OpenShift and Kubernetes](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/architecture/core_concepts/index.html). You probably want to either delete or scale down the DeploymentConfig.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The deployment config (and related replication controller) is the reason your pod is getting recreated when you delete it. The replication controller's job is literally to "ensure that a specified number of replicas of a pod are running at all times."

To destroy the pod (and leave the deployment config and other resources intact, just run: `oc scale dc <dc-name> --replicas=0`

- Replication controller: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/architecture/core_concepts/deployments.html#replication-controllers
- Manual scaling: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/dev_guide/deployments/basic_deployment_operations.html#scaling